# how to retrieve data of checkboxes from using Map String Object firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i upload data in firebase using this:

```
 HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    if(approved.isChecked()){
                    m.put("qDepartmentHeadApproval",approved.getText().toString());}
                    else{
                    m.put("rDepartmentHeadApproval",rejected.getText().toString());}
```

i want to retrieve this data from firebase using this

```
Map<String, Object> map=(Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

but how can i?

i want to data will be retrieve in single textview form the selected checkbox from the firebase.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, please also show us what have you tried in code for reading that data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pushing a `Map` to firebase as a child, then when you use `dataSnapshot.getValue();`

you will get a map depending on if it's the right child key.

I know you already know this, but you know how to read a map don't you?

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

if (data.containsKey("qDepartmentHeadApproval")) {
    String s = (Strting) data.get("qDepartmentHeadApproval");
}
```

`s` is your data.
You're looking for the data with the key you used which in this case is `qDepartmentHeadApproval`.

The value returned is going to be a string because you pushed a string.

A map is Key to Value and `map.get("key")` returns the value for that key.

There's a lot of casting and you could eventually get errors in the future without actually checking the value properly.

The map firebase returns is always going to be `Map<String, Object>` in java, but it's not always going to be a map.

You could try something like so:

```
//suppress the unchecked cast warning
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void loadData() {
   Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue();
   //check if the value is a map.
   if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
       //cast the value to a map
       Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) value;
       //check if the map contains the key and the value is a string
       if (data.containsKey("key") && data.get("key") instanceof String) {
            String s = (String) data.get("key");
       }
    }
}
```

This based on Java 8. I understand it can be reduced with higher java.
You can also use GenericTypeIndicator for the `getValue()` but it doesn't really do much. It is just to handle the type erasure in java and remove the use for a warning.

You also could probably remove the `containsKey` part. I just keep it for reassurance.

Anyways.. you should check the values before casting. I know it's very repetitive but you will avoid a lot of potential issues in the future. Trust me.